# How I can implement Paging in MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, paging, wpftoolkit

I have a WPFToolkit Datagrid inside my user control. I am creating my user contrrol in mvvm pattern. How can I implement paging in datagrid?

Is there any default paging mechanism or Do we have to go with custom paging ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an implementation of a [PagedCollectionView](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fidE23B98B81F3358F85B5DE7B1FBD54B4324D3BB08.aspx?s=collectionviewgrouproot#L123)  in the Silverlight toolkit
Combine this with some samples from the [internet](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=392) and you will have paging in no time
Here are some samples with [MVVM and CollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc700358.aspx) [to get](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) [you started](http://weblogs.asp.net/monikadyrda/archive/2009/08/31/wpf-listcollectionview-for-sorting-filtering-and-grouping.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

For the benefit of future readers: I just answered practically the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305883/mvvm-paging-sorting/5306328#5306328), giving the source of a full implementation.